# Anyone how to resolve this warning - using Karate framework for UI automation

Tags: ui-automation, karate

[DEBUG] 2021-05-20 17:13:39.765 [main] c.i.karate - over-writing existing variable 'xyz' with new value: read('classpath:/testData/testFile.json')

[DEBUG] 2021-05-20 17:13:39.765 [main] c.i.karate - over-writing existing variable 'abc' with new value: read('classpath:/testData/SomthingtestFile.json')

I think due to these warnings my scripts are running very slowly.

@PeterThomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore this warning. It is because you are re-assigning a `def foo` to the same variable name.

You are welcome to contribute code if this bothers you too much.

Comment: thanks for the clarification
@Peter Thomas